# How to prevent endless loop in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a rest server and client which uses this API. I have a list of hotels and it had passed well until I added bidirectional dependencies to other entities.After that I start receive an endless array of entities which just repeat the same row in database.

It is my first project with hibernate so may be I made trivial mistakes of novice.

[image: Schema]

Hotel:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "hotels", schema = "", catalog = "mydb")
public class HotelsEntity implements HospitalityEntity{
private int idHotel;
private String name;
private String region;
private String description;
```

//    private byte[] photo;

```
private HotelPropertyEntity property;
private List<RoomEntity> rooms;


@OneToOne(mappedBy = "hotel")
public HotelPropertyEntity getProperty() {
    return property;
}

public void setProperty(HotelPropertyEntity property) {
    this.property = property;
}

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "hotel")
public List<RoomEntity> getRooms() {
    return rooms;
}

public void setRooms(List<RoomEntity> rooms) {
    this.rooms = rooms;
}

@Id
@Column(name = "id_hotel", unique = true)
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
public int getIdHotel() {
    return idHotel;
}

public void setIdHotel(int idHotel) {
    this.idHotel = idHotel;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "name")
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "region")
public String getRegion() {
    return region;
}

public void setRegion(String region) {
    this.region = region;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "description")
public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}
```

HotelProperty

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "hotel_property", schema = "", catalog = "mydb")
public class HotelPropertyEntity {
private int idHotelProperty;
private byte hasPool;
private byte hasTennisCourt;
private byte hasWaterslides;

private HotelsEntity hotel;


@Id
@Column(name = "id_hotel_property", unique = true)
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
public int getIdHotelProperty() {
    return idHotelProperty;
}

public void setIdHotelProperty(int idHotelProperty) {
    this.idHotelProperty = idHotelProperty;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "has_pool", columnDefinition = "BIT", length = 1)
public byte getHasPool() {
    return hasPool;
}

public void setHasPool(byte hasPool) {
    this.hasPool = hasPool;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "has_tennis_court", columnDefinition = "BIT", length = 1)
public byte getHasTennisCourt() {
    return hasTennisCourt;
}

public void setHasTennisCourt(byte hasTennisCourt) {
    this.hasTennisCourt = hasTennisCourt;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "has_waterslides", columnDefinition = "BIT", length = 1)
public byte getHasWaterslides() {
    return hasWaterslides;
}

public void setHasWaterslides(byte hasWaterslides) {
    this.hasWaterslides = hasWaterslides;
}

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "id_hotel_property")
public HotelsEntity getHotel() {
    return hotel;
}

public void setHotel(HotelsEntity hotel) {
    this.hotel = hotel;
}
```

Room:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "room", schema = "", catalog = "mydb")
public class RoomEntity {
private int idRoom;
private String roomType;
private int peopleCapacity;
private Boolean  booked;
private Boolean locked;

private HotelsEntity hotel;
private InventoriesEntity inventory;
private RoomPropertyEntity roomProperty;

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "room")
public RoomPropertyEntity getRoom() {
    return roomProperty;
}

public void setRoom(RoomPropertyEntity roomProperty) {
    this.roomProperty = roomProperty;
}

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "id_room")
public InventoriesEntity getInventory() {
    return inventory;
}

public void setInventory(InventoriesEntity inventory) {
    this.inventory = inventory;
}

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "id_hotel")
public HotelsEntity getHotel() {
    return hotel;
}

public void setHotel(HotelsEntity hotel) {
    this.hotel = hotel;
}

@Id
@Column(name = "id_room")
public int getIdRoom() {
    return idRoom;
}

public void setIdRoom(int idRoom) {
    this.idRoom = idRoom;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "room_type")
public String getRoomType() {
    return roomType;
}

public void setRoomType(String roomType) {
    this.roomType = roomType;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "people_capacity")
public int getPeopleCapacity() {
    return peopleCapacity;
}

public void setPeopleCapacity(int peopleCapacity) {
    this.peopleCapacity = peopleCapacity;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "booked", columnDefinition = "BIT", length = 1)
public Boolean getBooked() {
    return booked;
}

public void setBooked(Boolean  booked) {
    this.booked = booked;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "locked", columnDefinition = "BIT", length = 1)
public Boolean  getLocked() {
    return locked;
}

public void setLocked(Boolean  locked) {
    this.locked = locked;
}
```

Could you please advise what is a way or ways to tell hibernate to stop this cycle?

p.s
This code contains another one issue. I f I remove one to one dependency and remain only one to many I receive `failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.example.model.HotelsEntity.rooms, could not initialize proxy - no Session (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.example.model.HotelsEntity["rooms"])`

Comment: Hm, one thing I spot is that your Room.getInventory() uses "id_room" as the joincolumn and not "id_inventory" as I would expect.

Comment: IDE doesn't show "id_inventory" as an one of available options -- if I marked it as id_inventory it marked as erro. I suppose that it should contain a key from entity which declares dependency, isn't it?

Comment: Yeah, you're not going to get very far if you rely on your IDE to do the work for you. You have to understand your own stuff.

Comment: Gimby, I understand what are you talking about. I share this view that we must understand things which we use as a professionals. But there is another side: if you start use something at the first time you don't have knowledge how to use it and you need some toehold and I assume IDE tips is a good way. If I run application with this column name I receive RemoteFailureException. How I can do it right? Does I need to define soetihng else, e.g some property?

Comment: You assume wrong. Very wrong. A book is the way to start to understand things. Study, don't just start hammering away and hope for the best. I can't help you like this, it will be like trying to explain math to someone who hasn't learned about numbers yet. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to mark entity as not serializable for JSON. Please use @JsonIgnore or @JsonIgnoreProperties("field") on one of the sides of the relations (the annotation is class-level).

Comment: It works, but if I need to use SQL query to the entity which has @JsonIgnore I can't use operations with entity was marked as ignored